# I wish to bind to a list within a list in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, viewmodel

I have bound my `ItemsSource` in my `ItemsControl` to a list of ViewModels, called LDLTracks. Within an LDLTrack view model there is a list of coordinate objects I wish to bind to, however I'm not sure of the correct way to go about it.

I can do this via binding my canvas to the List of TrackViewModels and then within my

XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding LDLTracks}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <Canvas/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>

                            <Line  X1="{Binding X1}" Y1="{Binding Y1}" X2="{Binding X2}" Y2="{Binding Y2}" Stroke="{Binding LineColor}" StrokeThickness="5">
                                <Line.InputBindings>
                                    <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding FooCommand}"/>
                                </Line.InputBindings>
                            </Line>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
```

I wish to replace the `{Binding X1}` With a List of Coordinates, so ideally it would be Coordinates.X1, as Coordinates would be a list, however when I try that the only property you can bind to is the Coordinates List count. Any ideas?

Comment: If you need to repeat a list inside the data template you need another `ItemsControl` - each `LDLTrack` object in `LDLTracks` will be repeated by the first `ItemsControl` but the child-list also needs its own repeater/data template. I assume you want a list of all the coordinate objects inside the outer list (a nested list?)

Comment: So you want to display several `Line` elements per each object in `LDLTracks`, right?

Comment: That's correct @mm8

Comment: I see, would you mind having a crack at the syntax for that so I could get my head around it a bit if you have the time? Would appreciate it a lot @Charleh

Comment: Someone already posted with that exact example!

Comment: So they have, thank you! @Charleh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an inner/nested `ItemsControl` that binds to the `Coordinates` list:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding LDLTracks}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Coordinates}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Line X1="{Binding X1}" Y1="{Binding Y1}" X2="{Binding X2}" Y2="{Binding Y2}"
                              Stroke="{Binding LineColor}" StrokeThickness="5">
                            <Line.InputBindings>
                                <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding FooCommand}"/>
                            </Line.InputBindings>
                        </Line>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but you wouldn't happen to know the syntax for the Command in the mouse bindings if the command is located in my LDLTracks? I've tried: 

`<MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type viewModel:LDLTrackViewModel}}, Path=FooCommand}"/>` 

But it doesn't seem to work. Many thanks!

Comment: @danny10846: Please ask a new question if you have another issue. Don't post additional questions in the comments field.